# How do I include the Django settings file?

Tags: python, django, email, settings

I have a .py file in a directory , which is inside the Django project folder.

I have email settings in my settings.py, but this .py file does not import that file.

How can I specify to Django that settings.py should be used , so that I can use EmailMessage class with the settings that are in my settings.py?

Answer (score 7):

```
from django.conf import settings
```

should do it!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to call your python script you can use one of a couple ways to accomplish what you want. The first is purely inside the python file.

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

The second way is to setup your environment before calling the script

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yoursite.settings
```

Then from inside your script call

```
from django.conf import settings
```

That should set everything up for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
from mysite.settings import VARIABLE_NAME
```